# The query takes a long time

Tags: mysql, sql

am I doing this SQL code right? The query works, but it takes really long, 161 seconds (with LIMIT 2 set). Is there a way to optimize that?

```
 SELECT p.itemid as `id`,
    p.title as `name`,
    pb.data_txt as `birthdate`,
    pc.data_txt as `growth`,
    pd.data_txt as `eyes`,
    pe.data_txt as `desc`,
    pf.data_txt as `weight`,
    pg.data_txt as `sex`,
    ph.data_txt as `hair`,
    pi.data_txt as `dimensions`,
    pj.data_txt as `lang`,
    pk.data_txt as `school`,
    pl.data_txt as `know`,
    p.image as `image` 

FROM  `jos_sobi2_item` p 
    INNER JOIN `jos_sobi2_fields_data` AS pb ON pb.itemid  = p.itemid
    INNER JOIN `jos_sobi2_fields_data` AS pc ON pc.itemid  = p.itemid
    INNER JOIN `jos_sobi2_fields_data` AS pd ON pd.itemid  = p.itemid
    INNER JOIN `jos_sobi2_fields_data` AS pe ON pe.itemid  = p.itemid
    INNER JOIN `jos_sobi2_fields_data` AS pf ON pf.itemid  = p.itemid
    INNER JOIN `jos_sobi2_fields_data` AS pg ON pg.itemid  = p.itemid
    INNER JOIN `jos_sobi2_fields_data` AS ph ON ph.itemid  = p.itemid
    INNER JOIN `jos_sobi2_fields_data` AS pi ON pi.itemid  = p.itemid
    INNER JOIN `jos_sobi2_fields_data` AS pj ON pj.itemid  = p.itemid
    INNER JOIN `jos_sobi2_fields_data` AS pk ON pk.itemid  = p.itemid
    INNER JOIN `jos_sobi2_fields_data` AS pl ON pl.itemid  = p.itemid

WHERE
      pb.fieldid = 16 AND
      pc.fieldid = 17 AND
      pd.fieldid = 21 AND
      pe.fieldid = 13 AND
      pf.fieldid = 18 AND
      pg.fieldid = 19 AND
      ph.fieldid = 20 AND
      pi.fieldid = 22 AND
      pj.fieldid = 25 AND 
      pk.fieldid = 23 AND
      pl.fieldid = 24

LIMIT 2
```

I think part of the INNER JOIN is bad.

Comment: An index and use explain

Comment: Do you really need to join jos_sobi2_fields_data so many times?!? Why???

Comment: If any of those attributes are missing, this query will return no row for that id. And LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless. But apart from that, this is probably the fastest query, if not the most elegant. Indexes as above.

Comment: @jarlh It's an EAV. That's just how it works.

Comment: do a `explain select...` and look at the results. Probably one of the tables has no index on itemid. If you don't see something obvious in the results then post them here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using conditional aggregation instead:

```
SELECT p.itemid as `id`, p.title as `name`,
       max(case when fd.fieldid = 16 then data_txt end) as birthdate,
       max(case when fd.fieldid = 17 then data_txt end) as growth,
       . . .
FROM  `jos_sobi2_item` p INNER JOIN
      `jos_sobi2_fields_data` fd
      ON fd.itemid = p.itemid
GROUP BY p.itemId, p.title;
```

You can add as many fields as you like, and adding more fields will have little impact on performance.

If you really want this even faster, you can do the `limit` on the first table:

```
SELECT p.itemid as `id`, p.title as `name`,
       max(case when fd.fieldid = 16 then data_txt end) as birthdate,
       max(case when fd.fieldid = 17 then data_txt end) as growth,
       . . .
FROM  (select p.*
       from `jos_sobi2_item` p
       limit 2
      ) p INNER JOIN
      `jos_sobi2_fields_data` fd
      ON fd.itemid = p.itemid
GROUP BY p.itemId, p.title;
```